# Error when compling C file using MEX: 'gsl/gsl_types.h' file not found

Tags: c, macos, matlab, mex

So I am trying to MEX compile a .c file from the libeemd library (https://bitbucket.org/luukko/libeemd), but when I give it a go, the following error appears

```
Building with 'Xcode with Clang'.
Error using mex
In file included from /Users/neergaard/Dropbox/Studie/Master/Matlab/library/resources/libeemd/src/eemd.c:19:
In file included from /Users/neergaard/Dropbox/Studie/Master/Matlab/library/resources/libeemd/src/eemd.h:38:
/opt/local/include/gsl/gsl_rng.h:23:10: fatal error: 'gsl/gsl_types.h' file not found
#include <gsl/gsl_types.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

I am pretty sure that I have the gsl library installed, but how can I make sure that the header files point to the right location?

I am not experienced in this sort of thing, so any help would be greatly appreciated!.

Comment: You want to have look at the compiler's `-I` option. Out of the blue: Try adding `-I/opt/local/include/`.

Comment: Meaning what? How do I do that? EDIT: ah, just saw your update. I tried appending that as `mex -I/opt/local/include/ eemd.c` but that only resulted in more errors about undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Comment: Getting linker errors as `undefined symbol` indicates that compilation at least succeeded, as linking is done after compiling. :-)

Comment: But there is no mex files created?